# Abstract page setup

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%twoside yaz iki taraflı için
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=4 cm, right=2.5 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\let\LTXnumberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\LTXnumberline{#1.}}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {1em}% this gives a \quad of space
  {}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
tex.stackexchange.com is perfect
\end{abstract}

\section{sec1}
test
\subsection{subsec2}
test
\end{document}
```

this code gave an abstract part which is connected to the original text. I don't want it. I want to see an individual abstract page written in de page setup of the original text and has the thesis name above the title of abstract and a place in the table of contents. I can make every one of them separately but not as a whole.

Comment: I'm afraid your objectives aren't all that clear. E.g., you mention a thesis title, but you don't indicate what it looks like. Separately: Why is the font for subsection-level headers larger than the one for section-level headers, and why would you set `Times New Roman` as the sans-serif font? Please elaborate.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to delete the duplicate material from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`. Feel free to revert if you believe that this edit has deleted something crucial.

Comment: I'm sorry I create others files from original to ask questions to this site but sometimes forget to delete all silly mistakes which I already solved for original document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the abstract show up on a page all by itself, simply insert `\clearpage` instructions before and after the abstract-related material. To force an entry in the table of contents, insert an `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abstractname}` directive immediately before `\begin{abstract}` (but after `\clearpage`, naturally).

I'm afraid I can't provide suggestions on how to make the thesis title show up on the abstract page as you haven't provided any information about this title.

[image]

```
%% Compile with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%twoside yaz iki taraflı için
\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman} % really?!

\usepackage{titlesec}
\let\LTXnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{\LTXnumberline{#1.}}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
    {\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection} % same look as "\section"
    {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage %% <-- new
%
% Provide information related to thesis title
%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abstractname} %% <-- new
\begin{abstract}
\texttt{tex.stackexchange.com} is perfect
\end{abstract}

\clearpage %% <-- new
\section{Sec1}
test
\subsection{Subsec1.1}
test
\end{document}
```